# android BottomSheet not expand to maximum height

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I am facing issue with BottomSheetBehaviour.BottomSheet is not expanding to maximum height at the start. However, it is scrollable to its maximum height. But i don't want scrolling rather want BottomSheet expand till its maximum height.
I tried setting height of the bottomSheet to whole screen with

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixels = (int) (BOTTOM_HEIGHT_DP * scale + 0.5f);
        bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = pixels;
```

also i tried setting

```
((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior.setPeekheight(pixels);
```

I also tried to handle through BottomSheetBehaviour callbacks

```
  @Override
                public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                        newState=BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED;
                    }

                }
```

Findings....

**STATE_EXPANDED: the fully expanded state of the bottom sheet, where either the whole bottom sheet is visible (if its height is less than the containing CoordinatorLayout) or the entire CoordinatorLayout is filled.**
I think this may be the reason(the entire CoordinatorLayout is filled) . but I am not able to find out if CoordinatorLayout is filled or not.
i have not defined CoordinatorLayout in layout.

Comment: I also thought this may be because of layout issue. but it can be scrollable up to maximum height . just can't figure out why does not expand in one go.

Comment: Can you post your layout.xml?

Comment: please show your xml layout for bottom sheet

Comment: @manishKumarSingh did u find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

In onCreate method :

BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomsheetlayout);
                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(pixels);

Comment: Not worked. I think setPeekHeight is about setting the height of Collapsed bottomsheet.. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html#setPeekHeight(int)